# What is the defacto standard for sharing variables between programs in different languages?

Tags: c++, python, memory, udp, buffer

I've never had formal training in this area so I'm wondering what do they teach in school (if they do).
Say you have two programs in written in two different languages: C++ and Python or some other combination and you want to share a constantly updated variable on the same machine, what would you use and why? The information need not be secured but must be isochronous should be reliable.

Eg. Program A will get a value from a hardware device and update variable X every 0.1ms, I'd like to be able to access this X from Program B as often as possible and obtain the latest values. Program A and B are written and compiled in two different (robust) languages. How do I access X from program B? Assume I have the source code from A and B and I do not want to completely rewrite or port either of them.

The method's I've seen used thus far include:

- File Buffer - Read and write to a
  single file (eg C:\temp.txt).
- Create a wrapper - From A to B or B
  to A.
- Memory Buffer - Designate a specific
  memory address (mutex?).
- UDP packets via sockets - Haven't
  tried it yet but looks good.
  Firewall?

Sorry for just throwing this out there, I don't know what the name of this technique is so I have trouble searching.

Comment: I have voted to close as not an answer as I think it is overly general. There are many different approaches that can be taken, depending on the actual problem to solve: network connections (udp/tcp), pipes, files, shared memory, platform specific solutions (dbus), networked shared memory implementations... To obtain sensible answers you should state a particular problem to solve first.

Comment: I updated the question with a specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking particular questions, you should aim at providing as much information as possible. You have added a use case, but the use case is incomplete.

Your particular use case seems like a very small amount of data that has to be available at a high frequency 10kHz. I would first try to determine whether I can actually make both pieces of code part of a single process, rather than two different processes. Depending on the languages (**missing from the question**) it might even be simple, or turn the impossible into possible --depending on the OS (**missing from the question**), the scheduler might not be fast enough switching from one process to another, and it might impact the availability of the *latest* read. Switching between threads is usually much faster.

If you cannot turn them into a single process, then you will have to use some short of IPC (Inter Process Communication). Due to the frequency I would rule out most heavy weight protocols (avoid XML, CORBA) as the overhead will probably be too high. If the receiving end needs only access to the latest value, and that access may be less frequent than 0.1 ms, then you don't want to use any protocol that includes queueing as you do not want to read the *next* element in the queue, you only care about the *last*, if you did not read the element when it was good, avoid the cost of processing it when it is already stale --i.e. it does not make sense to loop extracting from the queue and discarding.

I would be inclined to use shared memory, or a memory mapped shared file (they are probably quite similar, depends on the platform **missing from the question**). Depending on the size of the element and the exact hardware architecture (**missing from the question**) you may be able to avoid locking with a mutex. As an example in current intel processors, read/write access to 32 bit integers from memory is guaranteed to be atomic if the variable is correctly aligned, so in that case you would not be locking.

Comment: Thanks for writing all that even without the info, although the assumptions that you made are correct. The languages the different source codes/scripts are written in are in C++, python script, Java, LUA script, and C#. I do not think I'm competent enough to be able to port the code from all of them to one language. I am using Windows XP and Windows 7. Platform is the Intel x86-64. I have shared memory before but did not know that Intel had that guaranteed feature!

Answer (score 2):

Well you can write XML and use some basic message queuing (like rabbitMQ) to pass messages around

Comment: While XML might be overkill, a message queue seems the best approach for most applications.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will be helpful, but I'm also a student, and this is what I think you mean.

I've used marshalling to get a java class and import it into a C# program.

With marshalling you use xml to transfer code in a way so that it can be read by other coding environments.

Comment: Ah, And here I thought xml files were for setup configuration. Just looked up the wikipedia article, the definition fits what I am looking for. Question is how fast is writing and reading to an xml file? My goal isn't to do a one shot transfer but a continuous stream of data while both programs are running.

Answer (score 0):

At my school they teach [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture). They shouldn't, it's an ancient hideous language from the eon of mainframes, it's a classic case of design-by-committee, every feature possible that you don't want is included, and some that you probably do (asynchronous calls?) aren't. If you think the c++ specification is big, think again.

Don't use it.

That said though, it does have a nice, easy-to-use interface for doing simple things.

But don't use it.

Comment: I would say the use or not of CORBA is not as simple. Java RMI, can use CORBA as a transport layer, gnome uses CORBA... I would not say that it is ancient. Sure it has problems, and more so that the standardization body is a huge immovable mammoth, but that does not mean that it cannot be a good solution for some uses.

Answer (score 0):

It almost always pass through C binding.